# What jQuery syntax would I use for finding the all of the first-generation UL tags within a parent tag (and all of its children)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following HTML, how can I select all of the 1st-generation UL tags such that I end up with the following elements: company, subnav_1 - subnav_4, enginTool, prodSup, qualRel and lit, but none of the ULs inside of those elements?

```
<div id="col1">
  <h2></h2>
  <ul id="company"></ul>
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="navcordion">
      <h2></h2>
      <div>
        <ul id="subnav_1">
          <li>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2></h2>
      <div>
        <ul id="subnav_2">
          <li>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2></h2>
      <div>
        <ul id="subnav_3">
          <li>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2></h2>
      <div>
        <ul id="subnav_4"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <ul id="enginTool"></ul>
  <h2></h2>
  <ul id="prodSup"></ul>
  <h2></h2>
  <ul id="qualRel"></ul>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <ul id="lit"></ul>
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

I've tried `#col1>ul`, `#col1 ul:first` and `#col1 ul:nth-child(1)`, but neither gives me all of the elements I'm after.

Comment: The best I've come up with so far is 

    $('#col1>ul, #col1 ul:first-child');

It does the trick, but I'm wondering if there's a single selector that can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add a class to them?
That would be the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `<ul>`s are only either in `<li>`s or `<div>`s, would this work? Only selects `<ul>`s that are children of `<div>`s.

```
div > ul
```

Using jQuery you should be able to filter by passing in the parent of `#col1` as the second argument to `$()` so you don't accidentally select other lists.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that didn't occur to me. It's so simple and grabbed exactly what I was after. Thanks!